# List.js library, can the page goto an anchor after sorting?

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, page-refresh, partial-page-refresh

I am using the List.js library to search and sort a `<table>` element. The table resides in the main content area of the page after the header, navigation menu, and sidebar. When I sort any of the sort-able columns in the table, the page reloads and jumps back to the top of the page. This is expected, but I am trying to find a way around this so that after the page reloads, it scrolls back to the start of the `<table>` element (or to an anchor I place there). I basically would love if the page didn't move at all after sorting a column. I have looked through List.js's documentation, but to no avail. Maybe someone out there has used List.js extensively and knows a work-around for this situation. 
I have the page up on my staging site right now if anyone wants to check out the problem: http://www.tomclark.info/staging/cca/find-an-acupuncturist.html

Comment: This is the tag on your site that does the sorting: `<a href="#" class="sort" data-sort="city">City</a>`. The `href="#"` is the trouble maker, as that will scroll to the start of the page. Can you edit that?

Comment: Yep! Using <button> instead of <a> works like a charm. Thanks!